# How can I check in C# that the Oracle Oledb provider is available on the machine?

Tags: .net, oracle, oledb

I would like to be able to detect on startup of my application if the oracle provider is installed and available.
Is there any obvious easy way to achieve this in C#?

Comment: by oracle provider, do you mean Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC)?  Or do you mean an Oracle client?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I want to avoid to throw an exception at runtime if we access that provider, I would rather have an early error message when I launch the application.

Comment: so you mean Oracle client, correct?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Oracle documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e23174/InstallODP.htm The Oracle.DataAccess.dll assembly is installed to the following locations:

.NET Framework 2.0: **ORACLE_BASE\ORACLE_HOME\odp.net\bin\2.x directory**

.NET Framework 4: **ORACLE_BASE\ORACLE_HOME\odp.net\bin\4 directory**

If you test for the existence of this assembly is should indicate if the provider is installed.

Comment: this will not tell me if the dll is properly registered. the fact that the files are here won't tell me if the dll is available.

Comment: Originally I thought it best to check the GAC of the machine but according to the Oracle documents, the GAC may not be updated depending on how the client is installed.  I don't belive you need the dll to be registered to use it.  The instant client http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html can be copied to a directory without registering the dll and it allows connect to Oracle DB.